# MySQL does not work on MacBook Pro after restoring from Time Machine

Tags: macos, mysql, time-machine

I just used Time Machine to restore my hard drive. However I am not able to connect to MySQL.

I get the following error when I type `mysql -u root -p`.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

And I get the following when I type `mysqld`.

I appreciate your input. Thanks in advance.

```
2014-04-02 11:27:56 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. 
Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/data/sokada-macbook.lower-test
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/data/sokada-macbook.lower-test
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] InnoDB: read can't be opened in ./ibdata1 mode
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Binlog end
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INSERTED'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-04-02 11:27:56 10635 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: I downloaded and installed an updated version of MySQL from their downloads section.

Answer (score 0):

I [uninstalled mysql by following this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x) and install it by using the following command.

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue after restoring from a Time Machine backup.  I had to completely reinstall MySQL to fix it as my `/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql` directory was corrupted.  I followed these steps:

1. Moved `com.mysql.mysql.plist` out of /Library/LaunchDaemons
2. Moved my old mysql installation out of /usr/local into /tmp
3. Downloaded latest version of MySQL source and installed:

   ```
    $ cd /usr/local/src
    $ sudo wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.24.tar.gz
    $ sudo tar -xzvf mysql-5.6.24.tar.gz
    $ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql-5.6.23 \ 
      -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
      -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 \ 
      -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci \
      -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/tmp/mysql.sock \
      -DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=1 .
   $ sudo make
   $ sudo install
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql-5.6.24 /usr/local/mysql
   $ cd /usr/local/mysql
   $ sudo chown -R root .
   $ sudo chgrp -R mysql .
   $ sudo chown -R mysql data
   $ sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
   ```

Update `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
    [mysqld]
    sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
    character-set-server=utf8
    collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    character-set-client-handshake=false
```

Follow post-installation instructions from running the `mysql_install_db` command.

At this point, I tried to copy my old data directories into my new set up, but because the old data directories were not part of ibdata1, I got an error that the tables of my old databases did not exist.  There are solutions out there for fixing the ibdata1 file, such as http://www.ipserverone.info/database/how-to-recover-an-orphan-innodb-database-from-ibd-file/, but they involved an action for each table which was going to take too much time for me.  I was able to recreate the databases and import the data from a previous dump.